# bswap result on gcc possibly incorrect

Tags: assembly, architecture

I'm piddling with assembly (ATT syntax on my little endian Linux box) and have a perceived issue with the bswap instruction.  My code is as follows:

```
 .code32
.section .data
stringa:
  .asciz "eax is now %x\n"
stringb:
  .asciz "ebx is now %x\n"
.section .text  
.globl main
main:
  movl $4, %eax
  movl $5,  %ebx
  xchg %eax, %ebx
  pushl %eax
  pushl $stringa
  call printf
  add $8, %esp
  pushl %ebx
  pushl $stringb
  call printf
  add $8, %esp
  bswap %eax
  pushl %eax
  pushl $stringa
  call printf
  add $8, %esp
  call exit
```

Notice the output:

*remnux@remnux:~/Assembly$ ./swap*

*eax is now 5*

*ebx is now 4*

*eax is now d000000*

***Note that gbd shows 0x5000000 (the expected result) when I dump the registers while debugging.***

5 becomes d (hex 13) in the shuffled byte in the stdout (but not in the register dump.)  This tells me that the 4th bit of the first byte is shown as being (incorrectly?) flipped.  If I do this in decimal the same result occurs, although it's obviously a little more difficult to decipher: 5 becomes 218103808 instead of the expected 83886080.  Just add 2^27 to 83886080 and you'll see what's going on.

Is this expected, and why?  Note that I am using 32-bit code on my 64-bit Ubuntu VM:

*remnux@remnux:~/Assembly$ uname -m*

*x86_64*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value in EAX isn't preserved across function calls. In fact `printf` will return a value in EAX, the number of characters written. In this case that's 13, the number of characters in `ebx is now 4` plus a newline character. So you're byte swapping the return value of `printf` rather than the value you previously loaded into EAX.

Comment: Indeed, it look as if eax and ecx are subject to being overwritten when invoking functions and system calls.  It was just (not so) fortuitous that my bit in question happened to be one power of a multiple of two greater than my msb in the byte that made me think there was some 'wizardry' setting that bit.

Comment: @patricio2626 You'll want to look up the calling conventions for the 32-bit x86 Linux ABI. Only EBX, ESI, EDI, EBP are preserved across calls.

Comment: ESP is also preserved, of course.  But yes, @patricio2626: see the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to a Q&A that explains what a calling convention is, and to the actual ABI docs.